# Isomorphisms on $L^p$ and $\ell ^p$ spaces.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm studying real analysis and I have some questions about isomorphism on $L^p$ and $\ell ^p$ spaces.

First of all, I want to see whether there exist infinite sets like $A$ and $B$ such that  $\ell ^p(B)$ is not isomorphic to a subspace of  $\ell ^p(A)$, with $p \in [1, +\infty]$?

And secondly, Let $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ and $(Y, \mathcal{N}, \lambda)$ be two probability spaces and let $p \in [1, +\infty]$. Now, I want to show that $L^p (X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ is isomorphic to a subspace of $L^p(X\times Y, \mathcal{M} \otimes \mathcal{N}, \mu \times \lambda)$.

Any help is appreciated. Also, if you know any books containing these things, please lemme know. I really need to know more about these spaces and their properties. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\ell^{p}(\mathbb R)$ is not isomorhic to any subspace of $\ell^{p}(\mathbb N)$ because the former is non-separable and the latter is separable.  [In $\ell^{p}(\mathbb R)$ define $e_t(x)=1$ if $t=x$ and $0$ otherwise.  Then $\|e_t-e_s\|_p=2^{1/p}$ whenever $t \neq s$ and this implies that $\ell^{p}(\mathbb R)$ is not separable].

Fix any $g \in L^{p} (\lambda)\setminus \{0\}$. Then the map $T$ defined by  $(Tf)(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$ is an isomorphism from $L^{p}(\mu)$ into $L^{p}(\mu \times \lambda)$. In fact $\frac 1 {\|g\|_p} T$ is an isometric isomorphism.